# validateIpnContent Error with PayPal

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have developed a Ecommerce website (virtuemart) The website checks out with PayPal. I am having an issue with IPN.

The situation:

Business PayPal Account checks out on the website goes through to PayPal. PayPal authorises transaction and the money is taken with no problem at all. No error comes back. The order status goes back into the website as confirmed.

Standard PayPal user checks out on the website goes through PayPal authorises the transaction and the money is taken. However I get an error for IP (see below)

ERROR validateIpnContent: VMPAYMENT_PAYPAL_ERROR_POSTING_IPN

The status of the order in the website is Pending.

I am confused on why a business account will go through but a standard account wont. This is a problem because the client doesn't get notified that an order is pending only when its confirmed but they do get an email to say there has been an error on the website.

I have spent over 10 hours looking at this issue with no luck at all :(

Comment: Please add exact versions of Joomla and VirtueMart.